# Minifying JSON responses

Tags: json, gzip

I have a web requests that returns thousands of JSON objects in the form of this:

```
 {
      "ID": [int],
      "IsActive": [bool],
      "FirstName": [string],
      "LastName": [string],
      "Type": [int],
      "COIStatus": [int],
      "Role": [int],
      "SubscriptionEmailAddress": [string],
      "TRDevice": null,
      "MobileVersion": null,
      "RoleDescription": [string],
      "Name": [string]
 }
```

The size of the responses can be 2.5 megs according to my Google toolbar and I want to reduce that payload. **Considering that my server uses gzip to compress all of its data, would reducing the length of property names (eg: change "IsActive" -> "IA", "SubscriptionEmailAddress" -> "SEA") decrease the actual payload?** I'm thinking this may not decrease the payload because gzip may already be doing this in the background to compress its data.

Comment: No, shortening your property names is unlikely to do much when you're already gzipping your output. But it's an easy thing to test!

Grab your json output, search replace your property names, and upload the new json-file to your server. When requesting it, it should also be gzipped, and you'll be able to compare the file sizes.

Answer (score -1):

simple answer, yes. json is text only so the if your variables are named
"r1", "r2", "r3"... will be a lot smaller than "somehugename", "someotherlongname", "somethingelse"...

but if you're the data provider, i would suggest adding *pagination* to your results. instead of making one huge request to just get a few results, just requesting say the last 10 would greatly reduce your payload.